# Прозрачный TopAppBar и видимый контент за ним в Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Изучаю Jetpack Compose и столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу сделать полупрозрачный TopBar, как на фото. Смоделировал в Figma.

[image: Желаемый результат]

Я попытался добавить прозрачность непосредственно в свойство `backgroundColor` через `.copy(alpha)`. Пытался использовать `Unspecified` для цвета, но это тоже не работает/ Попробовал найти подобную информацию, но всё не то, что мне нужно.

Ниже функция `Scaffold`

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldCompose() {
val navController = rememberNavController()

val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

val parentHeight =
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(
            navController = navController,
            items = listOf(
                BottomBarScreen.Home,
                BottomBarScreen.Key,
                BottomBarScreen.Chat
            )
        )
    },
    topBar = {
        TopBar()
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
        .padding(innerPadding)
    ) {
        BottomNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
}
```

Функция `TopBar` и сам он внутри.

```
@Composable
fun TopBar() {
TopAppBar(
    title = {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Room 611",
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    },
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent.copy(alpha = 0.1f),
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = {

        }) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Menu, "Menu",
                modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp)
            )
        }
    },
    actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = { // synchronize weather

        }) {
            Row() {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(29.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.weather_icon),
                    contentDescription = "Navigation Icon",
                    tint = Color.White,
                )
                Spacer(Modifier.width(4.dp))
                Text(
                    text = "13°C",
                    fontSize = 22.sp,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }

        }
    },
    contentColor = Color.White,
)
}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет как это сделать

Comment: А где в приведенном вами коде выставляется фон (который вы ожидаете увидеть под прозрачным тулбаром)?

Comment: `backgroundColor = Color.Transparent.copy(alpha = 0.1f)` - тут нужно задавать конкретный цвет с alpha. `Color.Transparent` сам по себе как бы прозрачный. В остальном же...прозрачность работает, просто контент внутри Scaffold сам по себе не заезжает за TopAppBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас используется `Scaffold`, он устроен так, что располагает `content` ниже, чем `topBar`. Поэтому, когда вы делаете прозрачность у `topBar`, под ним не будет проглядываться фон контента:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    topBar = { TopBar() },
    ...
) {
    MyContent(it)
}
```

Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, рисуйте `TopBar` поверх вашего контента, это можно сделать с помощью обычного Box:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    ...
) {
    Box {
        MyContent(it)
        TopBar(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо. Однако изначально я неверно поставил вопрос... Хотел, чтобы именно проскролленный чуть выше контент было видно позади TopBar. А сейчас он накладывается поверх изначально. Но насколько я теперь понимаю, через Scaffold это не сделать.

Answer (score 0):

У `Scaffold` есть параметр [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Scaffold(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.FabPosition,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)), необходимо выставить его в значение `Transparent`, чтобы увидеть задний фон:

```kotlin
Box {
    Image(
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_background),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )
    Scaffold(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        topBar = { TopBar() },
    ) { paddingValues ->
        MyContent(paddingValues)
    }
}
```